# Converting string time to date object

Tags: javascript, date

I have a time string of 11:11 AM in `activity.StartTime` , how do I turn it into a Date object ?

```
st = new Date(activity.StartTime);
```

It gives off an invalid date by doing `console.log(st);`

Comment: What date do you want to create from this time string, today's?

Comment: @Mike i only want to utilize date methods such as `getHours()` and `.getMinutes()`, so the date does not matter

Comment: getHours() and getMinutes() are deprecated. The Date in java is the amount of millisecondes since 1970.

Comment: If you only want hour/mins just pull them out of the string?

Comment: @AlexK. yes, something like that to compare with another date minutes/hours

Comment: @OresteViron—javascript is not java. *getHours* and *getMinutes* are **not** deprecated in javascript (ECMAScript).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
//Take your time as a string
var time = "11:11 AM";

//Split the time into three strings so you have something like this
time[0] // "11" hour
time[1] // "11" minute
time[2] // "AM" morning

var hour = time[0];
var minute = time[1];
var morning= time[2] === "AM" ? true : false;
```

The function you'll need to use is [hour](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/hour/) which allows you to set an hour feeding in the hour variable in the range of 0 - 24 so you'll need to add 12 if the morning is true.

Then use the [minute](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/minute/) function in the same manner.

This will give you a moment.js object which you can then get a normal javascript date from.